# I am trying to add some data in database using PHP, but it does not work

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is my PHP code starting and used connection type is PDO.

```
    //connection with server
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    try {
         $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=gujaratoil", $username, $password);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         echo "Connected successfully";
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
   }

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       //at the beginning null value is set
       $name = $emailaddress="";
       $sql  = "INSERT INTO                                                                                                                                                                         

 registration(name,emailaddress)VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[emailaddre 
        ss]')";                                         
  }
          ?>
```

I have tried all the solutions available; what should I do to solve this issue? I am using a PDO connection.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Please explain your issue and what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please update your title to only contain the _actual issue_. Use the question for additional info.

Comment: Not only should you show us _all_ relevant code, you _must_ include your _actual issue_ in your question. What happens? Error messages? Checked the error log? Computer blows up?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When using PDO you should use *prepared statements* rather than directly embedding variables in the SQL.

The reason, I believe, given the code above why the insert was failing was / is due to the lack of quotes around field names within `$_POST[]` ~ ie `$_POST[name]` which is likely to be causing `undeclared constant` errors

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POSt['emailaddress'];

$sql='insert into `registration` ( `name`, `emailaddress` ) values ( :name, :email )';
$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how this can be an _answer_ to the very unspecified question that doesn't explain the OP's issue at all?

Comment: I read the question to be the op was having issues inserting data into the db so tried to show how one should do it with PDO. I can see, looking closer at the original code what the issue was however ~ an issue that would have been prevented if the code had been written differently as spotting misquoted variables within a quoted string are not always easy t ospot

Comment: In my opinion, the question is of too poor quality to get an answer at all. And we actually don't know what the OP's issue is, since there's no info about any error messages or even the code that actually suppose to do the inserting. (I do agree that this is how the OP should do it, though).

Comment: Inside double quotes, you actually don't need to quote the array keys.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience i am trying to add some data in database. but can not complete it